# Verifying custom master exists before applying to a site

Tags: master-page, solution-package

I have a branding solution consisting of one feature to deploy a custom master to the site collection. A web scoped feature exists in a separate solution that when activated sets the custom master as the `MasterUrl` and `CustomMasterUrl`. I have separated this into its own solution as we have several branding packages, each having a master that shares the same name.

The problem I have is that if the master page does not exist when the web scoped feature is activated, the whole site blows up (understandably).

What I want is to verify that this custom master page exists. So far I've tried setting up an HTTP Request / Response and verify that the response is OK before setting the master URL, but it hasn't worked. I'm starting to wish I just dealt with having redundant code by having this web scoped feature as a part of each branding package - at least then I can set up a feature activation dependency.

So how can I verify that the master page exists in the expected location before I apply it?

Answer (score 2):

So in the feature receiver where you set the **MasterUrl** and **CustomMasterUrl** properties, just check to see if the feature that deployed the custom master to the site collection exists.

Here's an example on how to check for the existence of a feature in a site collection:

http://www.davidyardy.com/blog/post/2011/01/28/Feature-Exists-(Activated-on-SPSite).aspx

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check for the existance of the masterpage file, I would do something like this:

```
bool fileExists = web.GetFile(newMasterUrl).Exists;
```